# Narrow an undefinable type to non-undefined if other parameter is true

Tags: typescript

```js
// third-party library
type AnyFn = (...args: any[]) => any;
type UseRequestOptions = {
    ready?: boolean;
}
const useRequest = (fn: AnyFn, options: UseRequestOptions) => {
    const ready = options.ready ?? true;
    if (ready) {
        fn()
    }
}

// our project
const api = {
    getUser(id: number) { }
}
const useGetUserById = (id: number | undefined) => useRequest(() => api.getUser(id), { ready: !!id })

const id: number | undefined = 1;
useGetUserById(1)
```

When the `ready` option is `true`, the `useRequest` will execute the `fn` function.

I created a wrapper named `useGetUserById` based on `useRequest`. The `id` may be `undefined`.

All things work fine in runtime but at compiler time. How can the third-party library or user-side narrow the parameter `id` type to `number` when passed to `api.getUser()`? The only way is using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on user-side, like `api.getUser(id as number)`? Can it be done internally with the third-party library?

TSC throws an error:

> Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsCcBMC0AHAhrcBPUAbaAjWdTAKC2QFNQBBAO0wDFbQBeUACgDpv0BzAZwBcoVPQDaAXQCUrAHwj6AbjKZKoAKr8KAJQoBHAK4V+4APLJw0APa1+rUAG8SoF6FgVU8TAH5h+K1Y4HrTKAL4kAMY2JqAGWrqGxuD27ABmtMJ0jLQANKBWFta2wpo6+kYm5pbRMizyTq6gUbbJ7p7YbAXVtpxtXqDe3hCwRsqN0KkcfZgyDY2u6exSzq7h4SQg+QawoMiwVgBWFBHgkdHJqMjQ9nMuvBTgpbDs0PDCtAYAtvgUsLOgazOLViWgA4g8ngAhTAASXgKVe7y+Px2AB9YrR4BRUtBaBR4LV5HEyokTOwlnIRFdOPdHlpnq8pHkHG4PF5hABCDmvAHLIExRGgD7fX6gdEGTHY3H4+wARmUxPBdN+0Lh7FlUiAA)

Comment: There is also a non-null assertion (like, `!` after a variable) like `api.getUser(id!)`. It also removes `undefined` from the possible types.

Comment: @qrsngky Yeah, I know. This is not what I want. Type assertion and non-null assertion. Thanks. I expect TS control flow analysis can narrow the type.

Comment: You passed the `id` directly to `api.getUser` without passing through `if` or the likes. What kind of control flow are you expecting?

Comment: Yes, I didn't use `if` on the user side, but on the library side, it uses the `if` check `ready` option to decide whether to execute the `fn`. This means when the `fn` performs, the `id` must be `number`(ignore the zero value on this demo).

Comment: Control flow analysis across function boundaries is difficult and TS doesn't really even try; this is a known issue at [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and it's not clear how to implement the kind of analysis you want without causing unacceptable compiler performance problems.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?